# Reusing custom styles in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

New to material-ui here and trying to work out the best way of using the css in js. I can see from the demo code that inserting styles as classes is pretty easy using 'withStyles' but if I do the following I'd need to re-create the 'grow' and 'defaultPadding' styles in every component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';


function Dashboard(props) {

    const { classes } = props;

    return (

        <Paper className={classes.defaultPadding}>
            Hello
        </Paper>
    );

}

const styles = theme => ({
    grow: {
        flexGrow: 1
    },
    defaultPadding: {
        padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3 + 'px'
    }
});


export default withStyles(styles)(Dashboard);
```

I could easily create a factory method in an external file that returns a massive object containing all my default styles but I'd need to be able to pass the existing theme to it if I want to use things like 'theme.spacing.unit'.

So, is there a way to create a bunch of re-usable styles of my own, using theme values, then import them into any component?

Bonus question: Is it possible to create nested objects so I can do things like this? ...

```
className={classes.layout.header}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think creating an external factory method would work or you could also create a `ThemeProvider` to pass your theme to every component that needs the same styles.

In the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zq0qrom3om) I created two Dashboard components. One with `styled-components` just to show how a `ThemeProvider` works and the other component is using `withStyles`.

For `withStyles` factory I called it `sharedStyles` in the demo and with this you can create a new style object inside your components by calling it and spreading it to a new style (just if you need to add more styles).

Nesting inside `styles` seems not supported. You could create keys like `layout.heading` or flatten the object before using it (see code in the demo). Both not perfect and I wouldn't use it.

I'm personally prefering `styled-components` but you don't need to switch to it. You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/src/models/ThemeProvider.js) how they implemented it and use it in your code to pass the theme to your component.

The `ThemeProvider` is using [React Context-Api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Thanks Awolf, I've been de-railed for a couple of days but I'll take a look at the code you've written and check it works for me tomorrow and mark it as correct.